# Problems with Dart/JS interop in chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension, dart, dart-js-interop

What is the difference between:

```dart
context["recentlyUsedStations"] = ["Goetheplatz", "Marienplatz"];
```

and

```dart
context["recentlyUsedStations"] = new JsObject.jsify(["Goetheplatz", "Marienplatz"]);
```

I am using this on a chrome extension background page and am able to get the values in a popup page in both cases. If I try to change the list, then the first case produces an array of integers (value 0). The second case works okay.

Answer (score 3):

The first version defines a js variable named `recentlyUsedStations` with its value set with a js object `DartObject` containing a reference to the `["Goetheplatz", "Marienplatz"]` Dart object. From Js side this variable is almost unusable and should only be used to keep a reference on the Dart object. This way the Dart object can be retrieved by calling `context["recentlyUsedStations"]`.

**Without** `new js.JsObject.jsify(...)` :

```dart
final a = ['b', 'c'];
js.context['a'] = a;

// unusable wrapper on Js side
// display : [object DartObject]
js.context['console'].callMethod('log', [js.context['a']]);

// the reference is kept
// display : true
print(identical(a, js.context['a']));
```

---

The second version defines a js variable named `recentlyUsedStations` with its value set with a js object that has been created by converting `["Goetheplatz", "Marienplatz"]` to an equivalent js array `["Goetheplatz", "Marienplatz"]`. This way the data can be used on Js side but it forgets the reference on the original Dart object. So adding an element to the dart List will have no effect on the array on the Js side.

**With** `new js.JsObject.jsify(...)` :

```dart
final a = ['b', 'c'];
js.context['a'] = new js.JsObject.jsify(a);

// converted to an array on Js side
// display : [b,c]
js.context['console'].callMethod('log', [js.context['a']]);

// the reference has been forgotten
// display : false
print(identical(a, js.context['a']));

// adding an element on the original List has no effect on Js value
a.add('d');
js.context['console'].callMethod('log', [js.context['a']]); // b,c
```

Comment: Alexandre, are you sure that adding an element to the list on dart side is not reflected on the js side? In developer tools console I can observe the changes on the js object.

Comment: If you use `jsify` I am quite sure that adding an element to the dart Object has no effect on the Js object.

Comment: Using your example, the last line produces output *null*